# Error C#: Un DataReader ya está abierto en esta conexion, reader.close() no lo toma

Tags: c#, mysql, windows-forms

En una aplicación pretendo conectarme a una base de datos MySQL para obtener la información de unos estudiantes (es una aplicacion para una escuela).

Todo perfecto hasta que ocurre lo siguiente, al terminar de usa el MySqlDataReader, hago reader.close() de toda la vida, pero... No quiere cerrar el DataReader... inclusive al cerrar la conexión me tira una excepción diciendo que sigue abierto el DataReader ya "habiendo" cerrado el reader... **WTF?**

```
    private void ConstruirView() {
    List<eEstudiante> Estudiantes = new List<eEstudiante>();
    using (MySqlConnection conexion = Conexion.Conectar()) {
        MySqlCommand cmd = conexion.CreateCommand();

        try
        {
            conexion.Open();
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT (EstudianteData) FROM estudiantes";

            MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            adapter.Fill(ds);

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    var table = ds.Tables["Estudiantes"];
                    for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        var elemento = table.Rows[i];
                        eEstudiante estudiante = (eEstudiante)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(elemento["EstudianteData"].ToString());
                        Estudiantes.Add(estudiante);
                    }
                }
            }

            reader.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (conexion.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                conexion.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hasta aquí llega el código que me esta dando error. Esa función la utilizo para ingresar los datos a una DataViewGrid (Windows Forms)... Cabe resaltar que la información que tengo en la base de datos, es un objeto serializado de los estudiantes, es decir tengo 2 rows nada más, una de ID y otra donde almaceno la información de una clase estudiante en JSON y luego pretendo agarrar esa info y deserializar para luego agregar la info que yo quiera dentro del dataviewgrid.

Comment: Eso debe ocurrir porque te tira excepción antes de pasar por el `reader.Close()` y entonces, como en el `catch` solamente tienes un `throw` no captas la excepción y se va al `finally` que es donde te peta. Pon en el `catch` algo para captar la excepción que te salta y edita la pregunta poniendo el error que aparece.

Comment: Por que usas un adapter y un reader?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

te he modificado el código. Prueba y nos dices. Básicamente lo que he hecho ha sido evitar el uso del `Adapter` y del `Dataset` y emplear bloques `using` para cerrar conexiones y los `DataReader` cuando la ejecución del programa salga del bloque correspondiente.

EDITO: El problema que veo es el siguiente. Estás utilizando la misma conexión para `DataReader` y para `DataAdapter` Esto no es compatible, de acuerdo con MSDN: [Best Practices for Using ADO.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971481.aspx) en la parte que dice

> Only one DataReader can be open at a time, off of a single connection.
>   In ADO, if you opened a single connection and requested two recordsets
>   that used a forward-only, read-only cursor, ADO implicitly opens a
>   second, unpooled connection to the data store for the life of that
>   cursor, and then implicitly closes it. With ADO.NET, little is done
>   for you "under-the-covers". If you want two DataReaders open at the
>   same time, off the same data store, you have to explicitly create two
>   connections, one for each DataReader. This is one way that ADO.NET
>   gives you more control over the use of pooled connections.

La traducción, espero sea buena

> Sólo puede abrirse un DataReader a la vez, en una única conexión. En
>   ADO, si abres una única conexión y se solicita dos conjuntos de
>   registros que son usados con un cursor de sólo avance y sólo lectura,
>   ADO implícitamente abre una segunda conexión desagrupada en el almacén
>   de datos durante la vida de ese cursor e implícitamente lo cierra. Con
>   ADO.NET, esto se realiza bajo cuerda. Si quieres dos DataReaders
>   abiertos al mismo tiempo, usando el mismo almacén de datos, tienes que
>   explícitamente crear dos conexiones, una por cada DataReader. Esta es
>   la forma que ADO.NET te da mayor control sobre las conexiones
>   agrupadas.

```
    private void ConstruirView()
    {
        List<eEstudiante> Estudiantes = new List<eEstudiante>();
        using (var conexion = Conexion.Conectar())
        {               

            try
            {                    
                conexion.Open();
                using (var cmd = conexion.CreateCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT (EstudianteData) FROM estudiantes";

                    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
                    {
                        if (reader.HasRows)
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            { 
                                var estudiante = (eEstudiante)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(reader["EstudianteData"].ToString());
                                Estudiantes.Add(estudiante);                                    
                            }
                        } 
                    }                        
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Perfecto! Gracias por eso.
Si habia leído algo sobre las conexiones y eso, pero no había entendido bien... la Documentacion de MySQL es medio horrible de leer..
Muchas gracias por la información :P Ya logré entender mejor el uso de los Adapters y Readers

Comment: Una pregunta: No requiero de cerrar al final la conexion al usar Using?

Comment: No. Al final del bloque `using` se realiza  el `Close()` y el `Dispose()` del objeto de forma transparente.